# SQL: How to get left column attribute of Max value in the right column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and have a question about how to execute a Query 
I have the following table

[image]

how do I return for Each Product ID which is the Country that the item sold the most at

so the answer should be :

```
1: United States 
2: United States/ Brazil (Either one but not both)
3 Peru/ United States  (Either one but not both)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by productid order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  A correlated subquery would return *all* rows that match the maximum.  The use of `row_number()` guarantees that only one row will be returned per product.